# working with two entity context from two diffrent server at the same time

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

In my project I have two separate server with separate Entity context, at the first I am fetching data from one server and saving it into a list by this code:

```
BarForooEntities1 bfe = new BarForooEntities1();
SaleHistory sh = new SaleHistory();
RadifsSendCenter rs = new RadifsSendCenter();
BaskoolEntities be = new BaskoolEntities();
var q = (from d in bfe.RadifsSendCenter
    where d.Daryaft == true
    orderby d.id_rec
    select d).ToList();
```

And then i save that list to another server database by using this code:

```
foreach (var v in q)
        {
            sh.id_rec = v.id_rec;
            sh.Radifkolsal = v.Radifkolsal;
            sh.Dates = v.Dates;
            sh.DateErsal = v.DateErsal;
            sh.TimeErsal = v.TimeErsal;
            sh.Karkhane = v.Karkhane;
            sh.Namekala = v.Namekala;
            sh.Vazn = v.Vazn;
            sh.Bandal = v.Bandal;
            sh.Dobaskul = v.Dobaskul;
            sh.OldYear = v.OldYear;
            sh.Sal = v.Sal;
            sh.del = v.del;
            sh.edit = v.edit;
            sh.Daryaft = v.Daryaft;
            sh.Shobe = v.Shobe;
            sh.Greid = v.Greid;
            sh.TedadBas = v.TedadBas;
            sh.Rahgiry = v.Rahgiry;
            sh.Tozih = v.Tozih;
            sh.NoeShemsh = v.NoeShemsh;
            sh.Metrazh = v.Metrazh;
            sh.Keyfiat = v.Keyfiat;
            sh.Address = v.Address;
            sh.City = v.City;
            sh.Karbar = v.Karbar;
            sh.CodeKala = v.CodeKala;
            sh.CodeGoruh = v.CodeGoruh;
            sh.CodeKG = v.CodeKG;
            sh.CodeGreid = v.CodeGreid;
            sh.Tel = v.Tel;
            sh.ShenaseMeli = v.ShenaseMeli;
            sh.Sefaresh = v.Sefaresh;
            sh.Tolid = v.Tolid;
            sh.Shenase = v.Shenase;
            var u = (from bu in be.BarbariUsers
                where bu.UserName == Login.username
                select bu).FirstOrDefault();
            sh.UserID = u.UserID;
            sh.ReceiveUser = Login.username;
            sh.ReceiveDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            be.SaleHistory.Add(sh);
            rs.Daryaft = false;
        }
be.SaveChanges();
bfe.SaveChanges();
MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

When I run my project,everything is working, but just one row of list is added to second list and also updating the first database value(rs.Daryaft = false;) doesn't change anything.
I know that if I move (be.SaveChanges();) and (bfe.SaveChanges();) inside of foreach loop, just the first one work with taking long time and the second one doesn't make anything. Maybe I'm going a wrong way.
Any suggestion or other solution to solve this problem?

Comment: You should create the new objects inside the loop.

Comment: I did it, but sometimes it works and sometimes not. i completely got confused of it.

Comment: You should make a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces your issue, so we have something to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your mention, it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Finlay I solve my own question. This is the edited code, maybe to be usefull for someone:

```
 BaskoolEntities be = new BaskoolEntities();
 BarForooEntities1 bfe = new BarForooEntities1();
 var q = (from d in bfe.RadifsSendCenter
     where d.id_rec > last
     orderby d.id_rec
     select new
               {d.id_rec,d.Radifkolsal,d.Namekala,d.Vazn,d.Bandal,d.Greid,d.TedadBas,d.Tozih,d.NoeShemsh,d.Metrazh,d.Keyfiat,d.Address,d.City,d.Tel,d.ShenaseMeli,d.Sefaresh,d.Tolid,d.Shenase
                     }).ToList();
        {
 foreach (var v in q)
            {
                RadifsSendCenter s = new RadifsSendCenter();
                SaleHistory sh = new SaleHistory();
                sh.id_rec = v.id_rec;
                sh.Radifkolsal = v.Radifkolsal;
                sh.Namekala = v.Namekala;
                sh.Vazn = v.Vazn;
                sh.Bandal = v.Bandal;
                sh.Greid = v.Greid;
                sh.TedadBas = v.TedadBas;
                sh.Tozih = v.Tozih;
                sh.NoeShemsh = v.NoeShemsh;
                sh.Metrazh = v.Metrazh;
                sh.Keyfiat = v.Keyfiat;
                sh.Address = v.Address;
                sh.City = v.City;
                sh.Tel = v.Tel;
                sh.ShenaseMeli = v.ShenaseMeli;
                sh.Sefaresh = v.Sefaresh;
                sh.Tolid = v.Tolid;
                sh.Shenase = v.Shenase;
                var u = (from bu in be.BarbariUsers
                    where bu.UserName == Login.username
                    select bu).FirstOrDefault();
                sh.UserID = u.UserID;
                sh.ReceiveUser = Login.username;
                sh.ReceiveDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                var b= (from h in bfe.RadifsSendCenter
                    where h.id_rec == q.id_rec
                    select h).FirstOrDefault();
                b.Daryaft = false;
                be.SaleHistory.Add(sh);
            }
    be.SaveChanges();
    bfe.SaveChanges();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
```